# CSS - Page wont scroll

Tags: css

Having some problems, cant get the page to scroll or get scrollbar to appear. But it will scroll when middle mouse button is clicked.

Any ideas?

http://t-webdesign.co.uk/projects/geusa/job_posting.html

My stylesheet: http://t-webdesign.co.uk/projects/geusa/style.css

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to

```
overflow: auto;

/* END OF RESET*/
/*Background class*/
.bg {width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 5000;}
body {font-size: 62.5%; font-family: Tahoma, arial, verdana, sans-serif; overflow: auto; background-color:#000; color:#cbcbcb;}
#container {position: relative; width: 920px; margin:0 auto; z-index: 6000; font-size:11px; text-align:left; padding:15px; line-height:15px;}
```

Comment: @user195257 consider accepting the answer for this question as it is a valid one that does fix your problem.